# Renaming all files and directories in NSLibraryDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

How can I rename all files and directories to lower case in `NSLibraryDirectory\myFolder`?

I found that I can to use:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:[oldPath lowercaseString] error:&error];
```

to renaming directories.

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
```

To getting array with directory contents but how I can check if `directoryContent[0]` is directory or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this to check if a NSUrl is a directory or file:

```
for (NSURL *item in directoryContent) {
    NSString *path = [item path];
    BOOL isDir;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        if (isDir) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a directory", path);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a file", path);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ does not exist", path);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To rename all contents of your directory you could use this:

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
BOOL isDir;
for (NSURL *item in directoryContent) {

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        if (isDir) {
            // create a new directory with lowercase name,
            // move contents of old directory to the new one
            // then delete the old directory
        } else {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:path toPath:[path lowercaseString] error:&error];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good for knowing isDirectory of file but I need to recursive rename all files and directory to lowercase

Comment: Updated my answer with code to rename the content of a directory

Answer (score 0):

```
//Call [self purgeDirectory:__NSLibraryDirectoryPath];


+(void)purgeDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath __deprecated_msg("For debug purposes only") {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath error:&error];
    for (NSString *itemPath in directoryContent) {
        BOOL isDir;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:itemPath isDirectory:&isDir]) {
            if (isDir) {
                [self purgeDirectory:itemPath];//subdirectory
            } else {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:itemPath error:&error];
            }
        }
    }
}
```